# How to add dropdown list in gridview excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Currently my method is use for export excel file from gridview. Now I want to create dropdown list in some column for each row of excel file. It's possible to do with StringWriter?

There is my code of the method...

```
string exportFileName = Session["corpUser"].ToString() + "_ProjectExport_" + unixTimestamp + ".xls";
//Create a dummy GridView
GridView dummyGridView = new GridView();
dummyGridView.AllowPaging = false;
dummyGridView.DataSource = dt;
dummyGridView.DataBind();
//Write Dummy Gridview to Excel File
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + exportFileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
dummyGridView.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: If you have the datasource attached to the gridview, I am not sure what is stopping you to extract the data from it to populate it in dropdownlist.

Comment: @JamshaidK. I finding the solution to populate the dropdown list with StringWriter.